# Как убрать <script src="libs/.../...js</script>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет!
Подскажите возможно ли отключить скрипт, который вызывает всплывающий модальный диалог, при уходе посетителя с сайта

```
<script src="libs/arcticmodal/config.js">
```

Если он кликнул по одной из ссылок

```
<a href="#">Заказать звонок</a> и <a href="#">Написать нам</a>
```

Содержание index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <a href="#">Заказать звонок</a> <!--Ссылка по нажатию на которую всплывает crm-форма-->
  <a href="#">Написать нам</a> <!--Ссылка по нажатию на которую всплывает crm-форма-->
 </header>
 <div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis similique deleniti repudiandae aliquam natus voluptatibus, odit obcaecati provident sequi dolorum molestiae quod modi corporis porro sit, ullam mollitia accusantium quos.
 </div>
 <footer>
  <a href="#">Заказать звонок</a> <!--Ссылка по нажатию на которую всплывает crm-форма-->
  <a href="#">Написать нам</a> <!--Ссылка по нажатию на которую всплывает crm-форма-->
 </footer>
 
 <div class="modalInner" style="display: none;"> <!-- Всплывающий модальный диалог-->
  <div class="offer"> <!--За него отвечает <script src="libs/arcticmodal/config.js"></script>-->
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
   <button type="submit" class="button_popup">Отправить</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="libs/arcticmodal/config.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Содержимое файла libs/arcticmodal/config.js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function($) {
    $(function() {
      if (!$.cookie('smartCookies')) {
        function getWindow() {
          $('.offer').arcticmodal({
            closeOnOverlayClick: true,
            closeOnEsc: true
          });
          $('#mark').addClass("good");
        };

        $('html').mouseleave(function(e) {
          if ((e.clientY < 0) && !($("#mark").hasClass("good"))) {
            getWindow()
          }
        });

      }

      $.cookie('smartCookies', true, {
        expires: 31,
        path: '/'
      });

    })
  })(jQuery)
  $('.fff').submit(function() {
    if (!$(this).find('input:checked').length) {
      alert('Выберите один из вариантов');
      return false
    }
    $.cookie('smartCookies', true, {
      expires: 31,
      path: '/'
    });
  }).find('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('input:text').prop('required', this.checked).attr('placeholder', this.checked ? 'Напишите комментарий' : '')
  });
});
```

**Спасибо!**

Comment: Как скрипт не работал? ну уберите из `html`

Comment: Он отвечает за всплывающий модальный диалог, когда нажимаешь на ссылки всплывают интегрированные crm формы. Нужно сделать так, чтобы по клику на ссылки отключался модальный диалог

Comment: Я не пойму скрипт вам нужен или нет? и если в нем что то не нужно или надо менять, то замени. вопрос не понятен.

Comment: Скрипт нужен, но нужно чтобы он не срабатывал при клике на, одну из ссылок, прикрепил файл config.js

Comment: ну а когда срабатывал?

Comment: config.js сейчас работает так (кликнул или не кликнул на ссылку, выполниться), нужно чтобы было так (если кликнул по ссылке не выполнятся, если не кликнул выполниться)

Comment: $('header>a, footer>a').on('click', function(event){return false;});

Comment: config.js все равно работает после клика, но не работают интегрированные в ссылки crm формы